# OpenVPN Keeps Crashing

Tags: linux, windows, networking, vpn, openvpn

```
Oct 20 21:00:44 sb1 openvpn[2082]: <MY_IP>:28523 [vpntest] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]<MY_IP>:28523
Oct 20 21:00:44 sb1 openvpn[2082]: vpntest/<MY_IP>:28523 MULTI_sva: pool returned  IPv4=10.8.0.6, IPv6=(Not enabled)
Oct 20 21:00:44 sb1 openvpn[2082]: <MY_IP>:28522 WARNING: 'link-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='link-mtu 1576', remote='link-mtu 1376'
Oct 20 21:00:44 sb1 openvpn[2082]: <MY_IP>:28522 WARNING: 'tun-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='tun-mtu 1532', remote='tun-mtu 1332'
Oct 20 21:00:45 sb1 openvpn[2082]: <MY_IP>:28522 [vpntest2] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]<MY_IP>:28522
Oct 20 21:00:45 sb1 openvpn[2082]: vpntest2/<MY_IP>:28522 MULTI_sva: pool returned IPv4=10.8.0.10, IPv6=(Not enabled)
Oct 20 21:00:46 sb1 openvpn[2082]: vpntest/<MY_IP>:28523 send_push_reply(): safe_cap=940
```

Client File:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote <IP> 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1410
persist-key
persist-tun
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo
```

SERVER:

```
port 443 #- port
proto tcp #- protocol
dev tun
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
reneg-sec 0
#mtu-disc yes
mssfix 1410
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/dh1024.pem
plugin /etc/openvpn/openvpn-auth-pam.so /etc/pam.d/login
#plugin /usr/share/openvpn/plugin/lib/openvpn-auth-pam.so /etc/pam.d/login #- Comment this line if you are using FreeRADIUS
#plugin /etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.so /etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.cnf #- Uncomment this line if you are using FreeRADIUS
client-to-client
client-cert-not-required
username-as-common-name
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 3 30
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
```

What is causing the VPN to keep dropping the connection and then reconnecting?

All the MTU settings are 1500. Where is the MTU issues coming from?

Comment: from openvpn doc "--link-mtu n
    Sets an upper bound on the size of UDP packets which are sent between OpenVPN peers. It's best not to set this parameter unless you know what you're doing." http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/65-openvpn-20x-manpage.html

Comment: what MTU is set on your physical interfaces?

Comment: What is the MTU on both server and client? (ifconfig)

Comment: Have you tried commenting the MTU settings and seeing if it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any https (for example apache) on the server? Because that can cause drop connection if can start... 
Try another port, and disable **comp-lzo** on server and on client too, because is a little buggy.